# How to get the result of the KieSession build (i.e. the rules compiler errors)?

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, drools

I am testing DROOLS 7.0 with a simple test Rule set using the following code:

```
KieContainer kc = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession("DroolsTestKS");
...
```

The KieSession instance is returned even if there are errors in the rule .drl file, and no exception is thrown. I would like to check the result of the rules compilation.
The Drools reference (see 4.2.2.4) says that the build result can be obtained with:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
assertEquals( 0, kieBuilder.getResults().getMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ).size() );
```

where *kfs* is a KieFileSystem instance, but the examples on how to build such a KieFileSystem in the previous pages of the manual are much more complex and a little bit confused IMHO.
Is there a way to have the Session buid result (i.e. to access a *KieBuilder* ) when creating a the KieSession  with the simple two lines of code I show at the beginning of this post ?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering to my question, because I've just found a solution:

```
KieContainer kc = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
Results rs = kc.verify("KBase");
if (rs.hasMessages(Level.ERROR)) {
  System.out.println("ERRORI DROOLS: " + rs.getMessages());
  ... // handle this
}
```

I'm wondering if with this validation the actual rules compilation is executed twice or not ... but anyway this method seems to work.